# Why I can't find a ResourceDictionary template in my visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am a beginner in Xamarin. Now I want to add a ResourceDictionary for making a Theme.

In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.resourcedictionary?view=xamarin-forms:

The Namespace of ResourceDictionary is Xamarin.Forms.

[image]

Whereas, there is not any ResourceDictionary template.

I tried to search it again:
[image]

There is nothing about this. I am using the Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.4. Why it turns out to be this and how can I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are mixing the terms here. *Namespaces* and *assemblies* are totally different things than the *New item templates* inside Visual studio. **ResourceDictionary** class is inside the **Xamarin.Forms**, indeed, and in the same time inside the **Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll**. This doesn't mean that it should be inside the new item template. There are a lot of other classes inside this namespace.

Having said that, you can create **ResourceDictionary** class in 2 ways:

1. If you want to write in it entirely in c#, what you will need is a **.cs** file. The file can be either **ContentPage (C#)** from the templates above (the second item from your screenshot), or a simple **.cs** calss file will do the work also. After that, inherit from ResourceDictionary class like so:

```cs
public class MyResourceDictionary : Xamarin.Forms.ResourceDictionary
{
}
```

2. If you want to write in it in xaml, then simply create a new **ContentPage** (the first item from your screenshot). Any other type of the combo **.xaml** together with a **.xaml.cs** code-behind file will work too. After the files have been created, change their structure **from**:

*MyResoruceDictionary.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LEUA.Services.MyResourceDictionary">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Hello, world!"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

*MyResourceDictionary.xaml.cs*

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyResourceDictionary : ContentPage
{
    public MyResourceDictionary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**to this**

*MyResoruceDictionary.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LEUA.Services.MyResourceDictionary">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

*MyResourceDictionary.xaml.cs*

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyResourceDictionary : Xamarin.Forms.ResourceDictionary
{
    public MyResourceDictionary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```